# Increase space between listings env. and surrounding text

Tags: spacing, listings

How can I set the space between a listing (lstlisting) and text that surrounds it? Is there a parameter I can set at the beginning of my document, that controls this? I tried `framesep`, but it just inflates the frame box.

EDIT:

```
text
\addvspace\medskipamount
\begin{lstlisting}
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

`\addvspace` does what I need. How do I set this at the beginning of the document, so I don't have to add this manually to every listing?

EDIT:

I use listings like so:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={cap},label=lbl]
 ... 
\end{lstlisting}
```

Where `cap` and `lbl` are different captions/labels, so they are not constant for all listings.

Comment: Try `\addvspace\medskipamount`? Don't understand your question really well though. Or maybe  a `\vskip5pt`. Is this a horizontal space or vertical space?

Comment: @azetina: I updated my question.

Comment: @qwe Why not make it into a `\newenvironment` or a `\newcommand` like `\newcommand{\mylist}[1]{\addvspace\medskipamount
\begin{lstlisting}
{#1}
\end{lstlisting}}`

Comment: [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) provides `aboveskip` and `belowskip`, both of which are `\medskipamount` by default. You could increase this using `\lstset{aboveskip=\bigskipamount, belowskip=\bigskipamount}` in your document preamble.

Comment: @Werner I didn't notice your comment while I was typing my answer.

Comment: @lockstep: I snooze, I lose. :-| No worries.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the `\lstset` command and its `aboveskip` and `belowskip` keys. See section 4.3 of the manual for details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{aboveskip=20pt,belowskip=20pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A listing}]
(Listing contents)
\end{lstlisting}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `\newcommand`:

```
\newcommand{\myconfiguredlisting}[1]{%
\addvspace\medskipamount %
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={cap},label=lbl] 
{#1} 
\end{lstlisting}}
```

Then use it in the form:

```
\myconfiguredlisting{content of listing goes in here}
```

Or

```
\newenvironment{mylst}
  {\addvspace\medskipamount %
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption={cap},label=lbl]}
  {\end{lstlisting}}
```

Then use the above as:

```
\begin{mylst}
....... % lst content goes here.
\end{mylst}
```

Comment: I use lstlisting like so: `\begin{lstlisting}[caption={cap},label=lbl]                                          ...
\end{lstlisting}`. Your solution doesn't seem to handle parameters?

Comment: I know that, just edit the solution as you please. I cannot update my answer thoroughly for now but I presume someone will post a more appropriate answer.

Comment: Sorry for being imprecise, I edited my question yet again.