# Distance between text and \lstlisting

Tags: spacing, listings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Increase space between listings env. and surrounding text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68894/increase-space-between-listings-env-and-surrounding-text)

Is it possible to increase the distance between text and an \lstlisting? In my resulting PDF the listing follows very short after the text:

[image]

Would that be possible?

Comment: Increase the value of `aboveskip` (default is `\medskipamount`). So, something like `\begin{lstlisting}[aboveskip=2\baselineskip]`.

Comment: Great! Thank you! It's so easy when you know it! ;-)